# why does iOS stimulator not hava the Location Services button？

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm doing my iOS APP, but there is a problem that the simulator could not show the location button in the Privacy of Settings page when I try to change the Location services on my App. Please help me fix that. Thanks.

[this is the situation like the picture shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/847MJ.png)

[Normally this page should be like the picture shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eB4Y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is apparently a [known bug](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693317), hopefully to be fixed in a future update